# Rendering textures not allowing other textures to show libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to render both the background and my character animation and my character tool all at once. This seems so trivial and yet I can't figure it out. Here is the code I have now for my rendering.

```
    batch.begin();
    
    if(player.getPosition().x > 14 * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE)
        tmpx = player.getPosition().x;
    else
        tmpx = 15 * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE;
    player.renderSprites(batch);
    worldScenes.render(batch, tmpx, surfaceCoordinates.y * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE);
    mapGrid.renderActual(batch);
    batch.end();
```

`player.renderSprites(batch);` renders my sprite animation then the tool he is using(a sword in this case) `worldScenes.render` renders the background and the `mapGrid.render` renders the dirt. When I run the above code here is the result
[image: Result 1]

Now when I run the following code (switching the `player.renderSprites` to the bottom):

```
    batch.begin();
    
    if(player.getPosition().x > 14 * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE)
        tmpx = player.getPosition().x;
    else
        tmpx = 15 * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE;
    
    worldScenes.render(batch, tmpx, surfaceCoordinates.y * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE);
    mapGrid.renderActual(batch);
    player.renderSprites(batch);
    batch.end();
```

Here is the result

[image: Result 2]

and lastly if I switch the `mapgrid.render` and `player.renderSprites`:

```
    batch.begin();
    
    if(player.getPosition().x > 14 * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE)
        tmpx = player.getPosition().x;
    else
        tmpx = 15 * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE;
    
    worldScenes.render(batch, tmpx, surfaceCoordinates.y * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE);
    player.renderSprites(batch);
    mapGrid.renderActual(batch);
    batch.end();
```

Here is the result:
[image: Result 3]

Now I don't want to spam pictures but if I put `worldscenes` last `player` first and `mapgrid` second it renders everything but the playersprites which consists of the player and the purple sword.

I just can't seem to find a pattern, something always overrides the other. Any help with this and I will be extremely appreciative I am so lost. Thank you!!

Comment: Please make that an answer @JohnathonHavens you saved me so many hours of me stupidly searching through my shaders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are blanking the screen preemptively, the dead giveaway is that the default clear color is black. I'd assume by the order of blanking that in your `player.renderSprites()` method the following line is in there somewhere.

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //clear the batch
```